# Why is entropy measured in bits?

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, keepass

I use `KeePassXC` to generate and store passwords. For example, generating a password with a length of 128 characters without using the extended ASCII character table, the entropy is about 770 - 800 bits. I have read that entropy in cryptography is **a measure of the randomness or diversity of a data-generating function**. But why in bits and how is this number calculated?

Comment: Why in bits? Because it's convenient. Instead of having to write "This password has an entropy of 18,446,744,073,709,551,616" you can say "It has 64 bits of entropy".

Comment: Oh, I got it, `i = log2(x)` where `i` is quantity of bits, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason we measure entropy in bits is because it's a convenient measure when working with computers.  Each additional bit of entropy adds twice as many possibilities.  So if, for example, a secret has 8 bits of entropy, then there are 256 (2^8) possibilities it could be.

Now, those 256 possibilities don't have to be exactly 8 bits (a byte long).  Picking uniformly from the set of strings from "1" to "256" would also provide a string with this much entropy.  What essentially matters is that the set of input strings, however we define or encode them, comes from a set of the appropriate size.